# Windows 7 Status Menu style Window

Tags: wpf, windows, expression-blend

I'm working on a project and I'm wondering how to get a type of window common in Windows's wireless controls, as shown in the screen shot below:

[image]

([source](http://cybernetnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/windows-7-wireless.jpg))

There's no close or maximize buttons, but the border is still present. My tools include Expression Blend 3 and Visual Studio 08. I was also wondering what the font used on these are, as it doesn't seem to be the normal Tahoma found in Office 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the font, but you can set `WindowStyle=None` on your Window to get the border-only effect.

Answer (score 2):

That font is Segoe UI. It comes with Office 2007 and Windows Vista/7.